# Ghost CMS show page excerpt on another page

Tags: javascript, ghost-blog

I have created a home template and I Was wondering if its possible to show a excerpt and image from the About page for example. I've been looking at the documentation to no success.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
   {{#get "pages"}}
    {{#foreach pages}}
        {{title}}
        <p>{{excerpt words="33"}}</p>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query posts that are pages, so this should work:

```
{{#get "posts" filter="page:true"}}
  {{#foreach posts}}
    {{title}}
    <p>{{excerpt words="33"}}</p>
  {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I also solved getting the page with filter="title:About+page:true", the ghost api helps with filter parameters https://api.ghost.org/v0.1/docs